# React Mui Autocomplete does not store the value until losing focus of the input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I have a functional Mui Autocomplete that lets the user select from options or make his own input. However, the value is not stored on useState when an option is clicked, only when the input loses its focus. I have checked some tutorials and apparently I have nothing different, but theirs work as expected (selected option on selection is stored as useState value).

[**CodeSandbox here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-euler-l0kc48?file=/src/App.js:615-1565)

```
<Autocomplete
    key={"casa"+index}
    freeSolo
    autoSelect
    fullWidth
    value={i.casa}
    onChange={e=>ponervalor(e,index)}
    options={casasNamesList}
    id={"casasNamesList"+index}
    size="small"
    color="primary"
    autoComplete={false}
    renderOption={(props, option) => {
       return (
       <span {...props} style={{ backgroundColor: "primary", border:"0.5px solid black"}}>{option}</span>);
    }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Casa" name="casa" variant="outlined" />}
  />
```

Edit: To add information, I believe the property `autoSelect` has something to do with this problem of mine, as it states:

> *If `true`, the selected option becomes the value of the input when the Autocomplete loses focus unless the user chooses a different
> option or changes the character string in the input.*

However, if I set it to false, the selected option is never stored as value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I was able to resolve it by not using onChange and use instead:

```
onInputChange={(e,newvalue)=>ponervalorcasa(e,newvalue,index)}
```